# How to change terminal to node in VS Code?(LInux mint)

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use Vue in Linux, I installed NODEJS via a guide and when i check which version i have using `node -v` i get the current version which is 15.11.0

I can't change the terminal in VSCode from sh 5.1 to node to be able to run node commands and commands related to Vue,React native and etc...

I tried almost everything i found in the web including here

What can i do? attaching a image of the terminal:
[image: Terminal]

Comment: Do you have installed NPM ? Make sure you've run "sudo apt install npm" and do "npm -v" for check that out

Comment: Gettings this error : Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

Comment: May your Mint OS corrupted and have some problems.. Anyway in my case I would do "sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade"

Comment: tried again after that => "sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade" and got this => E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: follow to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389170)

Comment: Tried everything following the guide, still the same error

Comment: What can I do, it's very weird

Comment: 1. You need to pay attention for all kind of logs that you got from error messages. 2. Search the appropriate stuff on internet. 3. For last step I would recommend you to reboot your system and install Mint again correctly, from [here](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=284). These are steps I would do..But I believe that there can be solution with 1,2

Comment: did u fix this error?